# SQL: Update multiple rows (Top 100) with sequential data

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I am working on SQL Server 2008 and trying to update a table. I just need the first one hundred rows to be updated with a 15 digit sequence. I have tried the following:

```
Declare @id varchar
Set @id = 2435435345962 

UPDATE TOP (100) Table1
SET @id = Column_nm = @id + 1 
GO
```

but I am getting the following error message:

> Msg 426, Level 16, State 1, Line 3
>   The length 1 of the receiving variable is less than the length 15 of the column 'Column_nm'.

Comment: Why are you declaring the variable as a `VARCHAR`...?

Comment: You also haven't specified an `ORDER BY` in your query.  `TOP 100` will return arbitrary rows unless you explicitly tell it what to order by.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Several things. You want start in 0 so you can add 00-99.

So lets start with the base

```
 WITH cte as ( 
       SELECT TOP 100 *,
              ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY somefield) -1 as rn -- row_number start with 1.
       FROM Table1 
       ORDER BY somefield
 )
 UPDATE cte
 SET anotherfield = '1234567890ABC' + REPLACE(STR(rn, 2, 0), ' ', '0')
                     ^^ 13 chars      ^^ two digits number
```

Answer (score 1):

The error message is about length of your variable. In SQL Server the default length of varchar is 1 (from msdn.microsoft.com i have only the french link sorry).

```
Declare @id varchar(15)
Set @id = 2435435345962 
UPDATE top (100) Table1
SET @id = Column_nm = @id + 1 
GO
```

You must declare id with length of 15 to put your string in this variable.

Comment: the id have 13 digits, OP want add 00-99 as last digits to make it 15